# React native packager fails to create jsbundle

Tags: react-native

I just upgraded react-native version to 0.48.1 from 0.30 and I am facing a weird issue. 
I fixed all the peer-dependencies for the libraries that I am using. then ran command,

> react-native start

running above command starts packager. Now when I hit below url to generate jsbundle,
http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false

I am getting below error,

```
"message":"Ambiguous resolution: module '$PROJ_ROOT_DIR/index.android.js' tries to require 'react-native', but there are several files providing this module. You can delete or fix them: 
$PROJ_ROOT_DIR/node_modules/jest-react-native/node_modules/react-native/package.json
$PROJ_ROOT_DIR/node_modules/react-native/package.json"
```

$PROJ_ROOT_DIR is my project directory path.

I don't have any '$PROJ_ROOT_DIR/node_modules/jest-react-native/node_modules/' directory in my setup. 
I tried deleting node_modules directory then running npm install. but nothing changed.

I have also tried, clearing packager cache by running command,

> ls -l $TMPDIR/react-*

but nothing happened.

Has anyone faced similar issue? any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your package.json file here.

Comment: Moreover why this command `react-native start`?

Comment: My bad. Yes it was a caching issue. npm start -- --reset-cache solved the issue. packager.sh file location changed RN 0.48 so my setup was not able to locate packager.sh file and npm start was not working.
I assumed that `react-native start` and `npm start` might be same. But they are not.

Comment: I have been using `react-native start -- --reset-cache` and nothing was happening. wasted few hours. :(

Comment: So is it working or not?

Comment: Yes, it's working now. Thanks :)

Comment: Cool. No problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone else facing same issue of similar issues, Clearing cache using below command worked for me.

> npm start -- --reset-cache

I was trying `react-native start -- --reset-cache` command which does nothing(my bad.).

Comment: For future reference: The `--` is to tell `npm` to pass the rest of the argument to the `start` script, i.e. `react-native start --reset-cache` would also work. Doc for `--`: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/cli.html#cli_1